# How to create a form allowing multiple checkbox selection in Wix?

Tags: forms, checkbox, velo

Does anyone know if there's a possibility to create a form where users can select multiple checkbox options instead of just one?  I need users to be able to check multiple boxes. Any help for a newbie would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're referring to the Wix website tool, Wix is the wrong tag. If you're building an MSI installer with WiX you need to specify more detail, such as checkboxes in the MSI UI, the WiX bootstrapper UI or something completely different.

Comment: Ok as I said I'm completely new to this so I'll have to look up those options and figure out what they are first. I thought I specified in the question what I needed and I thought it was pretty clear. I don't really care how I need to "build" it I just need it done. I'll look on a different forum since I apparently am not as experienced in coding or building these things as most.

Comment: Re-tagging to `wixcode` (from wix) - pretty sure it is the website tool that is being referred to. With the proper tag, someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but if you're using Wix Forms, you can click on the form, click the plus sign, then click "Selection" in the left column, then click "Multi Checkbox Field" to get checkboxes where users can select more than one. Right now you're probably using Radio Buttons, which are often used as the default in most form templates but only allow for one box to be selected.

Comment: There is no "Multi Checkbox Field" in the Selection